# getting timestamp for RSConnect pins

Tags: r, pins, rsconnect

I am working with a shiny app that reads data in pins. I want to get the date when the pin was created, and was able to find this function "pin_info" that is useful.

Below is an example I found.... So my question is: How can I just grab "created_time" that is under "Extended:" section below?

Thanks so much!

```
pin_info("mtcars", board = "rsconnect")
# Source: rsconnect<jluraschi/mtcars> [table]
# Extended:
#   - id: 5639
#   - guid: 9b6ae382-ebec-45de-8546-ee779e33ed10
#   - access_type: acl
#   - url: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/5639/
#   - vanity_url: FALSE
#   - bundle_id: 13400
#   - app_mode: 4
#   - content_category: pin
#   - has_parameters: FALSE
#   - created_time: 2019-08-21T02:22:56.546011Z
#   - last_deployed_time: 2019-08-23T15:55:25.435595Z
#   - build_status: 2
#   - run_as_current_user: FALSE
#   - owner_first_name: Javier
#   - owner_last_name: Luraschi
#   - owner_username: jluraschi
#   - owner_guid: ac498f34-174c-408f-8089-a9f10c630a37
#   - owner_locked: FALSE
#   - is_scheduled: FALSE
#   - rows: 14
#   - cols: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pin_info("mtcars", board = "rsconnect")$created_time
```